# Really slow when getting maximum distance between m nodes (Backtracking) (c++)

Tags: c++, algorithm, max, distance, backtracking

I've been asked to make an exercise using Backtracking, or Backtracking + Branch and Bound, where the imput data are n, m and a matrix(n x n). The n, represents a number of people, and the m, some people from the n. In the matrix, there are the distances among them, and the distances between i and j is different from the j and the i.

I am trying to get the maximum distance i can get from m nodes, that distance is the sum of the distance of all of them. For example, if i choose the node 1, 2 and 4, the result is the sums: distance(1, 2) + distance(2,1) + distance(2, 4) + distance(4, 2) + distance(1, 4) + distance(4, 1).

I have used Backtracking with Branch and Bound (iterative, not recursive), storing the nodes (structs where i store the current value and nodes used) that may get me to a solution. This nodes stores de lower and upper bound, i mean, the lower and higher solution I can obtain if i keep on using this node and his sons. From a node x, I generate all the possible nodes (nodes that are not used), and I check if this node may get me to a solution, if not, this node is discarded and erased.

The code i have implemented to make this, works, but it is really slowly. With low values of n and m, it is quick, but if i use higher numbers it is really slowly.

This is the main function and the others functions that are used:

```
void backtracking(int **matrix, int n, int m){
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////
/*
Part where I try to get the minimum/maximum that I can get from the beginning of the problem
*/

// Lists where I store the values from the matrix, sort from the minimum to the maximum, and from
// the maximum to the minimum. The values are the distances, I mean, the sum of matrix[i][j] and 
// matrix[j][i].
list<int> listMinSums; // list of minimum sums
list<int> listMaxSums; // list of maximum sums

int nMinimumSums = floor((m*m - m)/2); // rounding down
int nMaximumSums = ceil((m*m - m)/2); // rounding up
/*  
 * m*m - m = Given m nodes, there are m*m - m sums.
 * 
 * I count matrix[i][j] + matrix[j][i] as one, so there
 * are (m*m - m)/2 sums.
 */

for (int i = 0; i < n; i++){
    for (int j = 0; j < i; j++){
        int x = (matrix[i][j] + matrix[j][i]);
        // to differentiate from the minimum and maximum sums, I use false and true
        aLista(listMinSums, x, nMinimumSums, false); 
        aLista(listMaxSums, x, nMaximumSums, true);
    }
}
int min = 0;
int max = 0;
int contador = 0; // counting in every iteration to not surpassing the minimum/maximum sums
list<int>::iterator it = listMinSums.begin();
while (it != listMinSums.end() && contador < nMinimumSums){
    min += *it;
    it++;
    contador++;
}
contador = 0;

list<int>::iterator it2 = listMaxSums.begin();
while (it2 != listMaxSums.end() && contador < nMaximumSums){
    max += *it2;
    it2++;
    contador++;
}
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

// LLV = List of Live Nodes. Where I store the nodes that are going to
// guide me to the solution
list<nodo*> llv; 

// I do not store the root node, i store the first n nodes, of the first level.
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++){
    nodo *nod = new nodo(n);
    nod ->level = 0;
    //lower bound. It's the lower solution i can get from this node
    nod ->ci = min; 
    // upper bound. The higher solution i can get from this node.
    nod ->cs = max;
    // estimated benefit. If i have to choose from one node or another, i choose the one with higher
    nod ->be = (min+max)/2;
    // The node i is used
    nod ->used[i] = true;
    // Inserting this node to the list of live nodes.
    insert(llv, nod);
}
int solution = 0; // Initial solution
int c = min; // c = variable used to not use a node and his "sons", anymore
while (!empty(llv)){
    nodo *x = erase(llv, n); // erasing the node with the highest estimated benefit from the llv.

    if (x ->cs > c){
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++){ // Creating every son of the x node...
            if (!(x ->used[i])){ // ... that has not being used yet
                nodo *y = new nodo(n);
                y ->level = x ->level + 1;
                for (int j = 0; j < n; j++){
                    y ->used[j] = x ->used[j];
                }
                y ->used[i] = true;

                // Adding the values. For example, if node 1 and 2 were inserted, and this is the node 4,
                // adding matrix[1][4]+matrix[4][1]+matrix[2][4] + matrix[4][2]
                int acum = 0;
                for (int k = 0; k < n; k++){
                    if (k != i && consult(x ->used, k))
                        acum += matrix[i][k] + matrix[k][i];
                }
                y ->bact = x ->bact + acum;

                // Getting the lower and upper bound of this node y.
                cotas(y, x, i, y ->level, n, matrix);

                y ->be = (y ->ci + y ->cs)/2;

                // Node where i can get the solution
                if (y ->level == (m-1) && y ->bact > solution){
                    solution = y ->bact;
                    if (y ->bact > c)
                        c = y ->bact;
                }
                // Checking if i can update c
                else if (y ->level != (m-1) && y ->cs > c){
                    insert(llv, y);
                    if (y ->ci > c)
                        c = y ->ci;
                }
                else{
                    // i cannot use this node anymore, so i delete it.
                    delete y;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
cout << solution << endl;

liberacionMemoria(matrix, n); // freeing the memory used in the matrix
```

}

```
void liberacionMemoria(int **matriz, int n){
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        delete[] matriz[i];
    delete[] matriz;
}

void insert(list<nodo*> &t, nodo *x){
    list<nodo*>::iterator it= t.begin();
    t.insert(it, x);
}

/*
 * Getting the node with hightest estimated benefit from the list of live nodes
 * */
nodo* erase (list<nodo*> &t, int n){
    nodo* erased = new nodo(n);

    erased ->level = -1;
    erased ->be = -1;

    list<nodo*>::iterator it= t.begin();
    list<nodo*>::iterator it2;
    while (it != t.end()){
        nodo* aux = *it;
        if (aux ->be > erased ->be){
            it2 = it;
            erased = aux;
        }
        else if (aux ->be == erased ->be && aux ->level > erased ->level){
            it2 = it;
            erased = aux;
        }
        it++;
    }
    t.erase(it2);
    return erased;
}

/*
 * Checking if in the array of nodes used, the node in the x position it's used
 * */
bool consult(bool *nodesUsed, int x){
    if (nodesUsed[x])
        return true;
    return false;
}

bool empty(list<nodo*> &t){
    list<nodo*>::iterator it= t.begin();
    return (it==t.end());
}

bool aLista(list<int> &t, int x, int m, bool MayorAMenor){
    list<int>::iterator it = t.begin();
    int contador = 0;
    while (it != t.end() && contador < m){
        if (!MayorAMenor){ // lower to upper
            if (*it > x){
                t.insert(it, x);
                return true;
            }
        }
        else{
            if (*it < x){
                t.insert(it, x);
                return true;
            }
        }
        contador++;
        it++;
    }
    if (it == t.end() && contador < m){
        t.insert(it, x);
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}


void cotas(nodo *sonNode, nodo *fatherNode, int elegido, int m, int n, int **matriz){
    int max = 0;
    int min = 999;

    // Getting the sums from the chosen node with the already used
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++){
        if (consult(sonNode ->used, i)){
            if (elegido != i){
                int x = matriz[i][elegido] + matriz[elegido][i];

                if (x > max)
                    max = x;
                if (x < min)
                    min = x;
            }
        }
    }

    min *= (m-1);
    max *= (m-1);
    min += fatherNode -> bact;
    max += fatherNode -> bact;

    sonNode -> ci = fatherNode ->ci - min;
    sonNode -> cs = fatherNode ->cs - max;
}
```

I think, that the reason of going really slow with n and m a bit high, it is really slowly, it is because of the upper and lower bounds of the nodes, that are not accurate, but i don't know how to make it better.

I've been many days thinking how to do it, and trying to, but nothing works.

Here there are some examples:

Given an n = 4 and m = 2 and the following matrix:

```
0 3 2 4
2 0 4 5
2 1 0 4
2 3 2 0
```

the result is 8. This works and it is quickly.

But with n = 40 and m = 10 it never ends...

I hope someone may help me. Thanks.

****EDIT******

I may not have explained well. My doubt is, how can i know, from a node x, the less and the maximum I can get.

Because, the length of the solution nodes depends on m, but the solution changes if i choose some nodes or others, and I don't know how to be sure, of obtaining the less and the maximum from a node, but being accurate, to be able to cut the others branchs that do not guide me to a solution

Comment: Combinatorial explosion. As n and m get, consider how many alternatives you need to search. 4*2=8, but 40*10=400 (50x more). It looks like 50x more list inserts too thought I don't know what aLista does.

Comment: The funcion "aLista":

bool aLista(list<int> &t, int x, int m, bool MayorAMenor)

Add the value x into the list t.

I control how many sums are going to be in each case, that depends of the given m, and thats the m that I pass in the parameters. I calculate doing: m*m - m

For example, If i have m = 2, there are 2 sums, the sum from the first person and the sum for the another one. 2*2 -2 = 2. If i count matrix[i][j] + matrix[j][i], 2 sums, as one, it will be 1 sum.

If i have m = 3, there are sums between:

1-2, 1-3, 2-1, 3-1, 2-3 and 3-2, so we have 6 sums, 3 if I count every 2 sums as one.

Comment: The parameter "MayorAMenor", just controls if the list will have the numbers sorted from higher to slower or on the other way.

So, when i have finished of inserting elements calling to this function, the two lists will have the minimum and the maximum elements of the array. So I will use this elements to get the minimum and the higher i can obtain from the beginning.

For example, if i sum every number in the minimum list and i get 8, and i do the same in the maximum list and i get 20, i will know for sure that the result will be between 8 and 20.

Or at least, thats what i want.